# Two duality theorems

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

Suppose $X$ is a Hilbert space with norm $||.||$ and $K$ is a weak compact and convex subset of $X$.

The supporting functional:   $$h(x^*)=\sup_{x\in K} \langle  x^*, x \rangle$$

The indicator function:  $$\delta  (x|K)=0  \phantom{0}if  \phantom{0} x\in K \phantom{0} and  \phantom{0}+\infty\phantom{0}  if  \phantom{0}x\notin K$$

What is the relation between the following two duality theorems? Are they equivalent and 2 implies 1?

1. $$\delta  (x|K)=\sup_{x^*\in X}  \langle  x^*, x \rangle - h(x^*)$$
2. $$ \inf_{x'\in K}||x- x' ||= \max_{||x^*||\leq 1}  \langle  x^*, x \rangle - h(x^*)$$
3. Will the following claim be true:   Fix  any $1\leq M< +\infty$,

$x\in K$ if and only if for all $x^*$ satisfying $||x^*||\leq M$, we have

$$  \sup_{||x^*||\leq M}  \langle  x^*, x \rangle - h(x^*)=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

The statement (1) is the observation that $\delta(\cdot|K)$ is the convex conjugate of $h$ (and vice-versa). So (1) is always true under your assumptions. The function $h$ is usually called the support functional of $K$.

The statement (2) states that there is no duality gap between the primal problem 
$$
\min_{x'\in X} \|x-x'\| + \delta(x'|K)
$$
and its dual
$$
\max_{x^*\in X}\ \delta(x^*|B) + \langle x^*,x\rangle - h(x^*)
$$
with $B$ being the unit ball.
Observe that $f^*(x^*)=\delta(x^*|B) + \langle x^*,x\rangle$ is the conjugate of $f(x')=\|x-x'\|$.

Question (3) is related to the primal problem above by a scaling with $M$,
$$
\min_{x'\in X}\ M^{-1} \|x-x'\| + \delta(x'|K)
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So (3) is also a true statement?